# Inline NOT operator using boolean

Tags: javascript, boolean-operations

I have this snippet of code:

```
if (bool) {
    return <code that outputs bool>;
} else {
    return !<same code that outputs bool>;
}
```

Is there a way to convert the above to something like this so that I don't have to write the code twice?

```
return (bool? !! : !) <code>;
```

Comment: ```return (bool ? <code that outputs bool> : !<same code that outputs bool>)```

Comment: @Kevin.a the <code> is pretty long to be duplicated in a one-liner. My main intent is to not have to write <code> twice.

Comment: @bxk21 then extract the result to a variable?

Comment: MHO: My common sense detection is if you need to do this, seems like it is wrong pattern.

Comment: @VLAZ I was hoping I could avoid that. I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: So, you don't want to extract the result from running the code to a variable and the code is too long to go in a single line, yet you want to run this as part of a `return` statement? I'm not sure what you're actually after here.

Comment: So basically you have some method and you want to return the inverse based on state. So something like this is how it typically would be written. `var result = myFunction(); return bool? result : !result` So you want something that skips the ternary or if/else. In that case it is going to be a comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

```
return bool === <code>
```

I wrote down a truth table and saw this

```
      code
       T F
      +-+-
     T|T|F
bool  +-+-
     F|F|T
```

Which is the same table as bool = code

Comment: I ended up with `bool-codeThatOutputsBool() === 0`, which simplifies to exactly what you've got here. Nice one.

Comment: @TylerRoper Yeah I just saw your answer before you deleted it. Looks like we came to the same idea, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write the code twice, then extract the result to a variable or to a function

```
//sample <code that outputs bool>
var result =
```

or

```
function calculateBool(someObj) {
   return someObj.fetchA()
  && someObj.fetchB()
  && someObj.fetchC()
  && someObj.fetchD()
  && someObj.fetchE()
// etc...
}
```

so you can then simply do

```
if (bool) {
  return result
} else {
  return !result
}
```

this can be simplified to

```
if (!bool) {
  result = !result;
}
return result;
```

or

```
return bool? result : !result;
```

If you prefer to use boolean algebra to do a flip of the result, then you can use XOR. In JavaScript, the XOR operator will work on integers only, so it converts boolean values to `0` or `1` but you can just directly turn those into a boolean again implicitly `!!value` or explicitly `Boolean(value)`.

Here is how the XOR equation works `valueToFlip XOR bool` will invert the result for `bool = true` and `valueToFlip` being any value. If you want to only flip on `bool = false`, then you can simply invert it in the equation `valueToFlip XOR NOT bool:

```js
function describeFlip(valueToFlip, bool) {
  const result = Boolean(valueToFlip ^ !bool);
  console.log(`${valueToFlip} ${bool}: ${result}`)
}


describeFlip(true, true);
describeFlip(false, true);
describeFlip(true, false);
describeFlip(false, false);
```

Comment: Interesting. The caret operator is apparently the bitwise operator for XOR. I assume it doesn't do anything weird with raw booleans.

Comment: @bxk21 well, it converts them to numbers, as I said, but `true -> 1` and `false = 0`. The equality holds both ways, though directly converting to boolean restores the values: `!!1 = true` and `!!0 = false`. So, as long as you convert the end result, you get the same as a boolean XOR.

Comment: I want valueToFlip to flip if the bool is false, not true. So we would want a NOT XOR, right?

Comment: @bxk21 yes, you can invert `bool` before feeding it to the formula. I've amended the example to that.